# How many 8 digit palindromes are prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, palindrome

> Find the number of primes that are 8 digit palindromes.

I got this question in a entrance paper. The only thing I know is the definition of a palindrome.

Also, is there any method/formula to count or approximate the first $n$ palindromes?

Comment: Were you allowed to use a computer, or a programmable calculator? Otherwise this seems terribly unreasonable. You can skip about half the numbers because the first/last digits can't be 5 or even (esp not zero). But other than that it looks like it's still some 6000 numbers to test.

Comment: Hint:  write out a few and factor them.  A pattern should emerge.

Comment: Side hint:  the "$8$" isn't terribly important here.  Try $2$ first.  Same pattern.

Comment: @AlexMeiburg I wasn't allowed any calculator.The question was objective type with four options 0,1,11,19.

Comment: Given those options, the obvious answer is zero, even if you have no clue, why that is true. It is however easily seen to be true by knowing how to test a number's divisibility by $11$.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if you ever read the comments by lulu and myself? The number *eleven* plays a crucial role here...I mean if you have no freaking idea at all, you could at least take some 8-digit palindromes and have them factored by a computer. The pattern that lulu talks about is very hard to miss.

Comment: And of course there are even digit palindromes like 1221...

Comment: @MooS Thanks, i didn't notice that.

Comment: Many numbers are palindromic, but few of them are primes.

Answer (score 7):

Summarizing the hints and clarifications made in comments above:

One of the properties of prime numbers is that they cannot be divisible by any other number other than itself and $1$.

A palindrome is a number (or string) which is read the same forwards as backwards.  These can be of odd length like your example of $12321$ but they can also be of even length $12344321$.

The divisibility test for $11$ should work wonders here if you can pay attention how to apply it.

> The number $\overline{abcdefgh}$ is equivalent modulo $11$ to $-a+b-c+d-e+f-g+h$.  That is to say, $\overline{abcdefgh}$ is a multiple of $11$ if and only if $-a+b-c+d-e+f-g+h$ is a multiple of $11$.  (*remember zero is a multiple of $11$*)

Having used the divisibility test for $11$ will point out a crucial observation about any palindromic 8-digit number which will imply something about whether or not it can be prime.

Comment: is that mean every even digit palindromes are divisible by 11?

Comment: @ArpitYadav yes indeed.  The two-digit palindromes this should be obvious: $11,22,33,\dots$ and the information above should give the most important observations for proving this for arbitrary even-length palindromes.

Comment: thanks JMoravitz

Comment: 11^2=121, 111^2=12321, 1111^2=1234321... How such numbers can be primes?

Comment: @sirou all the palindromes are not prime, i think you didn't get the question, i want you to read it again...Thanks

Comment: you are right, I wanted to delete the comment. Sorry!

Comment: @sirous my comments above and outline to a proof leads to a proof that every even-length palindrome with the exception of $11$ cannot be prime (*because they are divisible by $11$*), but it does not touch on the case of odd-length palindromes.  Indeed, there exist prime odd-length palindromes: $2,3,5,7,101,131,\dots$ just as there exist many odd-length palindromes which are not prime: $1,4,6,8,9,111,121,\dots$.  Regardless, information about odd-length palindromes is irrelevant to the original question: whether an 8-digit palindrome could possibly be prime.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for showing interest and writing appreciable answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are none. In general, if $k$ is an even composite number, there are no prime palindromes with $k$ digits because they're all divisible by $11$. A few examples:

- $10000001 = 11 \times 909091$
- $10011001 = 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 73 \times 137$
- $10022001 = 3 \times 11 \times 83 \times 3659$
- $10033001 = 11 \times 97 \times 9403$
- $10044001 = 11 \times 139 \times 6569$

You get the idea.

> Also, is there any method/formula to count or approximate the first $n$ palindromes?

Trying to take this question at face value, the answer is absolutely yes, there's definitely a way to approximate how many palindromic numbers there are up to a given bound, if you're not concerned that they be prime. And if the given bound is a power of $10$, then it's easy to know with certainty. If $n$ is even, then there are $$11 \times 10^{\frac{n - 1}{2}} - 1$$ palindromes up to $10^n$, and if $n$ is even, there are $$2^{\frac{n}{2 + 1}} 5^{\frac{n}{2}} - 1$$ palindromes up to $10^n$.

Comment: thanks for lucid explanation